# Calling the backend REST interfaces to get a timetable of the train

Tags: javascript, angular.js

I'm very new to AngularJS and just started in a new project which uses AngularJS for Web UI. I was looking into our code and found out that we have huge functions in controllers. Like, one 100-LOC function which does a lot. Logically, our Sonar complains about it and for me as a novice it's quite difficult to understand what's going on.

A short summary of what the code does:

- The code calls the backend REST interfaces to get a timetable of the train.
- This timetable (basically a sequence of departures/arrivals to/from stop) is later on displayed in the UI.
- The retrieved timetable is used to prepare objects later on used by UI for the rendering.

I thought it would be good to structure these big functions in controllers in smaller functions. I'd like to have several smaller easier-to-understand functions, but I don't know what is the correct way to achieve this.

What I've found was [this resource](http://joelhooks.com/blog/2014/02/11/lets-make-full-ass-angularjs-directives/) which had an example of a controller function divided into smaller functions (see the `DropdownController`). Here's my take of this pattern on one of our controllers:

```
myControllers.controller('TrainDetailsController', ['$scope','trainResource', 'trainSequenceResource', '$location', '$log',
    function($scope, trainResource, trainSequenceResource, $location, $log) {

        var self = this;

        $scope.filter = {};
        $scope.stops = null;
        $scope.host_location = $location.host();

        this.reloadTrain = function() {
            if($scope.filter.date && $scope.filter.number) {
                $scope.stops = [];
                self.queryTimetable();
                self.queryTrainSequence();
            }
        };

        this.queryTimetable = function() {
            trainResource.query({
                number: $scope.filter.number,
                day: $scope.filter.date.day,
                month: $scope.filter.date.month,
                year: $scope.filter.date.year
            }, function (timetable) {
                self.processTimetable(timetable);
            });
        };

        this.processTimetable = function (timetable) {
            $scope.train = timetable.train;
            $scope.classification = timetable.classification;

            if ($scope.stops.length !== 0) {
                $scope.stops = [];
            }

            var hasCoupledTrain = false;

            for (var i = 0; i <= timetable.sections.length; i++) {
                var firstSection = i === 0;
                var lastSection = i === timetable.sections.length;
                var arrivalSection = i > 0 ? timetable.sections[i - 1] : null;
                var departureSection = i < timetable.sections.length ? timetable.sections[i] : null;
                var stop = self.createStop(arrivalSection, departureSection, firstSection, lastSection);
                $scope.stops.push(stop);
                hasCoupledTrain = hasCoupledTrain || stop.hasCoupledTrain;
            }

            $scope.hasCoupledTrain = hasCoupledTrain;           
        };

        this.createStop = function (arrivalSection, departureSection, firstSection, lastSection) {
            var coupledTrain = departureSection ? departureSection.coupledTrain : undefined;
            var isCouplingStart = arrivalSection && arrivalSection.coupledTrain === undefined && coupledTrain !== undefined;
            var isCouplingEnd = departureSection && arrivalSection && arrivalSection.coupledTrain !== undefined && coupledTrain === undefined;
            var showCouplingLine = coupledTrain !== undefined;
            var showCouplingFinalDecoration = (showCouplingLine && firstSection) || (lastSection &&  arrivalSection.coupledTrain !== undefined);
            var showCouplingStartDecoration = isCouplingStart;
            var showCouplingEndDecoration = isCouplingEnd;

            if (isCouplingEnd) {
                coupledTrain = arrivalSection.coupledTrain;
            }

            return {
                station: arrivalSection ? arrivalSection.arrival.station : departureSection.departure.station,
                platform: arrivalSection ? arrivalSection.arrival.platform : departureSection.departure.platform,
                //TODO: put planned platform here
                platformPlanned: null,
                arrivalTime: arrivalSection && arrivalSection.arrival ? arrivalSection.arrival.time : null,
                departureTime: departureSection && departureSection.departure ? departureSection.departure.time : null,
                departureSection: departureSection,
                arrivalSection: arrivalSection,
                status: arrivalSection ? arrivalSection.arrival.status : departureSection.departure.status,
                coupledTrain: isCouplingStart || isCouplingEnd ? coupledTrain : undefined,
                hasCoupledTrain : coupledTrain !== undefined,                
                showCouplingLine: showCouplingLine,
                showCouplingFinalDecoration: showCouplingFinalDecoration,
                showCouplingStartDecoration: showCouplingStartDecoration,
                showCouplingEndDecoration: showCouplingEndDecoration
            };
        };

        this.queryTrainSequence = function () {
            trainSequenceResource.query({
                    year: $scope.filter.date.year,
                    month: $scope.filter.date.month,
                    day: $scope.filter.date.day,
                    number: $scope.filter.number
                },
                function (trainSequence) {
                    self.processTrainSequence(trainSequence);
                }
            );
        };

        this.processTrainSequence = function(trainSequence) {
            $scope.trainSequence = trainSequence;
        };

        $scope.$watch('filter.date', function() {
            $log.info("Date changed. Reload Train.");
            self.reloadTrain();
        });

        $scope.$watch('filter.number', function() {
            self.reloadTrain();
        });

    }]);
```

I'd be grateful for a review. My main objective is to find out if it is the right way to structure controller functions. Should I move more code to the services? Is `self` and `this` usage OK? Is it OK to assign functions to `this` properties?

Answer (score 1):

Taking the example from the link you sent, which is good, you see the controller is doing not much, in their words '*Normal controller stuff!*'

The controller on the link provided is either watching (`$scope.$on`, `$scope.$watch`), doing an initialization (init) or some really small logic (init, toggle, `isOpen`)

You should aim for the same in your controller. Either watch a variable/event, or do some minimal logic.

For anything that is not a watch, use self instead of `$scope`, as in the example. ([Good article to that extent](https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/))

Supposing `trainResouce` and `trainSequenceResource` are services, you could call them directly on the view (HTML), even passing only `$scope.filter` and accessing the attributes inside the service method

The function to create a stop can definitely be extracted to a directive or service

Finally, for the `processTimetable` function, you could try the `angular.forEach` syntax.

Once you've done all that changes, you'll notice there is still big pieces of code on the bigger functions, which you can later try and divide in smaller ones.